# .deb files open in Archive Manager

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 and I cannot install any .deb file by double-clicking on them. Sure, I can run `dpkg -i blah.deb`, but I was wondering how I can reset that in the GUI? If I open the file's Properties > Open With, I can "Reset", but it sets Archive Manager, and I don't see any software installer app.

I don't usually install .deb files without a repository, and I have installed other Debian based distros that opens .deb files in the software installer (as expected); I don't remember if this system has ever behaved like this, or if something had gone wrong for some reason.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First let's update `mlocate` database, run:

```
sudo updatedb
```

now we should find `mimeapps.list` file:

```
locate mimeapps.list
```

it should return something similar to:

```
/home/ravexina/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Now open the above file using an editor, if it didn't had any result then create it yourself:

```
nano ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Under `[Default Applications]` look for a line which starts with:

```
application/vnd.debian.binary-package
```

change it to:

```
application/vnd.debian.binary-package=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
```

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file, close and reopen your file manager.

Now deb files are going to be open using "gnome softwares" and you are able to install them.

If you don't have "Gnome softwares", then install `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt install gdbi
```

it's a tools to install `deb` files, it should add itself as default application, however if it didn't add it's line to `mimeapps`:

```
application/vnd.debian.binary-package=gdebi.desktop;
```

Comment: I have already done this, and gdebi opens when I double click a deb file. My problem is that when I click "Install package" inside gdebi, it just closes and opens the package in Archive Manager.